# Getting navigation controller to launch one of two different views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, delegates

I have a program where we are using a navigation controller and need the app to launch to one of two different views. Basically if certain info has previously been entered then we need the app to launch to view A, but if the info has never been entered then we need it to launch to view B. I am having difficulty getting this to work and am wondering what ways if any I could implement this. I am certain it needs to be done in the app delegate but I am not sure how. Thanks in advance!